# Why is flatten declared on GenericTraversableTemplate and not TraversableLike?

Tags: generics, scala, scala-2.8, scala-collections

The signature of `TraversableLike.flatMap` is as follows:

```
def flatMap[B, Th](f : (A) => Traversable[B])(implicit bf : CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, Th]) : Th
```

The signature of `GenericTraversableTemplate.flatten` is:

```
def flatten[B](implicit asTraversable : (A) => Traversable[B]) : CC[B]
```

Why is the latter method (which seems to me to differ from `flatMap` only in the sense that the transformer function is `implicit`) not definable on `TraversableLike` as:

```
def flatten[B, Th](implicit asTraversable: (A) => Traversable[B], 
                   implicit bf : CanBuildFrom[Repr, B, Th]) : Th
```

Is there some reason that this must be the case?

Comment: Scala 2.7 or 2.8?  The collections lib has been revamped a lot in 2.8.

Comment: Not only have I tagged the question as 2.8 but it references the Traversable trait which doesn't even exist in 2.7!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer lies in the source code:

```
def flatten[B](implicit asTraversable: A => /*<:<!!!*/ Traversable[B]): CC[B]
```

The implicit parameter to `flatten` should actually be `A <:< Traversable[B]` (ie. an assertion that the generic parameter of `GenericTraversableTemplate` is itself `Traversable`). (See [this mailing list thread](http://old.nabble.com/-scala--Using-generalised-type-constraints-in-2.8-collections-td26249516.html) for discussion about why it's currently commented out.)  My understanding is that all the methods in this trait used to be defined on (some of) the companion objects of collection classes because they were only applicable for some instantiations (if that's the right word) of type parameters.  This `<:<` construct allows them to be made instance methods.